# Why does this double have [] directly after it?

Tags: java, double

I've come across this piece of code in a program I'm editing for an assignment:

```
    double[] colour = new double [3];
    colour[0] = 255; colour[1] = 0; colour[2] = 0;
```

I think it means that the value *colour* is a double which is made by combining three other values. Is there anything more that needs to be said about this? I mean, is that why the double has the [] brackets directly after it - to specify that it needs to take more than one value? I'm slightly confused by this...

Comment: `double[]` defines an _array_ of doubles

Comment: Read up on arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It means to the variable `colour` can be assigned an `array of double` values. `new double[3]` create an `array of doubles` with the size 3.

Comment: On a side note why is it working with double values? RGBA (In this case RGB) channels are unsigned bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The `[]` means that you have an array of doubles. Arrays let you have multiple things in a sort of list, so you can have three numbers: `[255, 0, 0]`

More info is available in the Java array documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

The [] indicates you are creating an "array of double". This is primitive array which means the size is fixed. In your case an array of size 3 is being allocated.

An alternate method would be to use the List interface:

```
List<Double> colour = new ArrayList<Double>(3);
colour.add(255);
colour.add(0);
colour.add(0);
```

For this example you could also have a class:

```
public class Colour {
  double r;
  double g;
  double b;

  public Colour(double r, double g, double b) {
     this.r = r;
     this.g = g;
     this.b = b;
  }

   ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `double[]` is an [*array*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) of `double` values.

In your particular case, `colour` is an array of size 3 (as specified on the right hand side of the assignment), and so you will access the three components using `colour[0]`, `colour[1]` and `colour[2]` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In  Java the `[]` after a type denote `Array` data structures.

In your case, you are creating an array of 3 double values.

Please refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) Oracle tutorial for more information regarding the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
double[] colour = new double [3];
```

say: length colour[] = 3, datatype double,

and:

```
colour[0] = 255; colour[1] = 0; colour[2] = 0;
```

asign to colour the values `[255, 0, 0]`

PD: I can't comment sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that `[]` denotes *array*, which can be thought of as a collection of objects (in this case, numbers of the `double` data type), you can think of it in layman's terms like this:

The `double[] colour` part of the statement kind of says "I am going to have this *collection* called `colour` and it's going to be a type of `double` number, but I don't know what values or how many it's going to have." Emphasis on the word *collection*, since that's what an array is.

The `new double [3]` part says "I am creating 3 new doubles". Since you never said what the 3 doubles are, you begin to state them:

"The first one is `255`, the second one is `0`, and the third one is `0`.", which in the code looks like this now:

`colour[0] = 255; colour[1] = 0; colour[2] = 0`

And I'm sure you might already know, but in computers, the numbers start counting up from `0` instead of `1`.

```
    [0]              [1]             [2]
First Element   Second Element   Third Element
```

Another example that helped me better understand arrays when I first started programming was thinking of a box of Oreos that has different flavors inside. The box is an *array*, the *type* of cookie is Oreos, the order in which they sit in the box represents their *position* (a.k.a. it's index), and the *values* are the flavor.